# Audio to text conversion in java

Tags: java, audio

I'm currently working on a project to retrieve multimedia data from a multimedia database. Can anyone suggest me a way to convert my audio files to text formats which would greatly help in the data retrieval.

Comment: Did you try Google? I mean Google search

Answer (score 0):

Gee, & I did this about a year ago, can't quite remember what I used, but a quick google brought up this

http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php

Comment: FreeTTS is for TextToSpeech, not SpeechRecognition which is OP wanted